# Open Webview when item in the side slide menu is clicked

Tags: android, mysql, android-fragments, slider

I am trying to create a new activity when we click on the menu in side slide navigation. I have successfully created a new activity when i clicked on the menu but when a new activity is opening in WebView the side slider is diapperaing which I dont want.
As an example for this my application is same as a facebook application in which when we click on any item say "Newsfeed" it opens the activity but the slide navigation is still there.Kindly let me know hoe to achieve it.Thanks in advance.

This is my main activity code:

```
package com.example.diarysystemforms;

import com.android.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.android.model.NavDrawerItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout ,mDrawer;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_DiarySystem);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
//      
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }



    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
//  private void displayView(int position) {
//      // update the main content by replacing fragments
//      HomeFragment fragment = null;
//      switch (position) {
//      case 0:
//          fragment = new HomeFragment();
//          break;
//      case 1:
//          fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
//          break;
//      case 2:
//          fragment = new PhotosFragment();
//          break;
//      case 3:
//          fragment = new CommunityFragment();
//          break;
//      case 4:
//          fragment = new PagesFragment();
//          break;
//      case 5:
//          fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
//          break;
//
//      default:
//          break;
//      }
//
//      if (fragment != null) {
//          FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
//          fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//                  .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
//
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
//          mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
//          mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
//          setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
//          mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
//      } else {
//          // error in creating fragment
//          Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
//      }
//  }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);         
    //You should reset item counter 
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    if ( position == 0 ) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeFragment.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        if ( position == 1 ) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CommunityFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }

//public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
//      long id) {
//  // display view for selected nav drawer item
//  displayView(position);
}
}

}
}
```

This is my activity code which is opening when I click on the item.As an example I have given activity code for only one activity:

```
package com.example.diarysystemforms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class HomeFragment extends Activity {
    private static final String PIC_WIDTH = null;
    WebView mWebView; 

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);
        //WebView web = new WebView(this);

        WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient()
           {
               // Override page so it's load on my view only
               @Override
               public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
               {
                // This line we let me load only pages inside Firstdroid Webpage
                if ( url.contains("DiarySystem") == true )
                   // Load new URL Don't override URL Link
                   return false;

                // Return true to override url loading (In this case do nothing).
                return true;
               }
           };


           // Get Web view
//         mWebView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
//          mWebView.setInitialScale(getScale());

           mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webview ); //This is the id you gave
           mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
           mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);       //Zoom Control on web (You don't need this
                                                  //if ROM supports Multi-Touch     
           mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //Enable Multitouch if supported by ROM
           mWebView.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);

           // Load URL
           mWebView.loadUrl("http://103.241.181.36:8080/DiarySystem/addvehtogrp.jsp");




       }//End of Method onCreate
```

}

this is my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_DiarySystem"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this is fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers(); in your code.

Comment: i tried this but it didnt worked.. an u suggest me any other solution